# Unity OneMouseDown second Object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a begginner in Unity.

I have a script, which arrange the movement of two game object.
I use OnMouseDown. It activates the GameObject where the click happened and let the movement (with keyboard).
My problem is if I click the second game object the first one still moves (both of them).
How can I turn off the movement for the first object?

```
 void OnMouseDown()
    {
      
      if (activeUnit==false ) 
      {
        activeUnit=true;
                      
        }
      else {activeUnit = false;}
    }


    void Movement (){

        if (activeUnit == true)
         {//here comes the movement method
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to limit the movement to exactly one object you could use a `static` instead your bool and go

```
private static YOURCLASS _currentlyActiveInstance;

void OnMouseDown()
{
    if(_currentlyActiveInstance == this)
    {
        _currentlyActiveInstance = null;
    }
    else
    {
        _currentlyActiveInstance = this;
    }
}

void Movement ()
{
    if (_currentlyActiveInstance == this)
    {
        //here comes the movement method  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Now I go and read after to understand why :)

Answer (score 0):

To toggle a variable first you should better use this syntax:

```
void OnMouseDown()
    {
      activeUnit=!activeUnit;
    }
```

You can add another function OnMouseUp to Untoggle the unit. So the full code should look like that:

```
void OnMouseDown() {
      ToggleUnit();
}
void OnMouseUp() {
      ToggleUnit();
}
void ToggleUnit() {
   activeUnit=!activeUnit;
}
```

Otherwise if you don't wanna use OnMouseUp to untoggle the Unit, you should add an EventListener that untoggle units when clicking

Comment: I don't think OP wanted to stop immediately when the mouse button is released but rather to stop the previously clicked object